Conditional type inference?
If I'm using the lru-cache package which has the class class LRUCache<K extends {}, V extends {}, FC = unknown>.
How do I make V reliant on what is passed as K?
Right now I'm doing:
  const myCache = new LRUCache<
    'AccountAPIOAuthToken' | 'EpicOAuthV2Token' | 'RPCAuthAuthPlayerV2',
    AccountAPIOAuthToken | EpicOAuthV2Token | RPCAuthAuthPlayerV2
  >(/* ... */);

However, I would like if K is 'AccountAPIOAuthToken', that V must be AccountAPIOAuthToken, etc.

Does this approach work for you?

So this q is about a particular third-party library and not just about TS, right? If so, could you [edit] to include enough of the type definitions for LRUCache that we can answer the q without requiring anyone navigate away from Stack Overflow to view them? • And please give definitions for AccountAPIOAuthToken etc, also, and the options object, so it's a [mre]. • I imagine the answer to this q will look like those to this question where you'd need to write an entirely new interface for it, which from my look at lru-cache, looks like a nightmare.
